# How to fix using raw function MAX in queryset API not getting maximum marks?

Tags: python, mysql, django, rest

views.py

```
class MaxMarks(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Marks.objects.raw('select student_id, subject_id, 
    sem_marks, id, internal_marks, MAX(total_marks) from 
    collegedetails.college_marks ')
    serializer_class = MarksSerializers
```

I'm trying to figure out max marks using raw funtion in views.py after mapping to URL pattern and start run server but it getting only one record but still there more records which haveing max marks, Can any one suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.student_id, 
       t1.subject_id, 
       t1.sem_marks, 
       t1.id, 
       t1.internal_marks, 
       total_marks
FROM collegedetails.college_marks t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t2.total_marks) total_marks
       FROM collegedetails.college_marks t2 ) t3 USING (total_marks);
```

Comment: is there anothey way to write  query easy to understand ,what is t1 and t2, t3?

Comment: @user17821553 *is there anothey way to write query easy to understand* Depends on precise MySQL version. *what is t1 and t2, t3* They're aliases.

Comment: this query  select id,student_id,subject_id, sem_marks, internal_marks, max(total_marks) from collegedetails.college_marks; working in mysql workbench but not working in raw api django what wrong in my query

Comment: @user17821553 *working in mysql workbench* No. It gives *some* output, not more - it in non-deterministic, read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html. If it matches to your expectations then you're lucky simply.